# Fail building a Docker container early with bad list of packages for yum install

Tags: linux, docker, rpm, yum, dnf

My Dockerfile wants some package `not-here-yet` that is not in the registered repositories.

```
RUN yum install -d 1 -y not-here-yet && yum clean all
```

This fails as expected. But because the container does not have `dnf`, the below returns exit code 0 even though it has the same problem.

```
RUN yum install -d 1 -y inotify-tools not-here-yet && yum clean all
```

`yum`'s poor validation in this area leaves me with an incomplete container unless the Dockerfile's maintainer knows what commands make `not-here-yet` available.

Assuming for policy reasons that I cannot install `dnf` on this container, how do I make `yum` fail if any one package is not found in a list **without** copying the same RUN line over and over again to install one package at a time?

Comment: may be `RUN yum update && yum install ...`

Comment: @user2915097 Some packages become available after installing other packages. `yum update` does not help until that happens. If one package in not available in a list, `yum` should fail. The problem is that it doesn't, and I don't want to duplicate code as a workaround.